# Define dependency in pyproject.toml depending on operating system

Tags: python, python-packaging, pyproject.toml, pdm

I am using `pyproject.toml` according to PEP 631 (i.e. NO `poetry`, I am using `pdm`). I need to specify a dependency version according to the operating system.

So far, I tried something like this:

```
[project]
...
dependencies = [
    "kaleido==0.0.3; platform_system!='Windows'",
    "kaleido==0.1.0post1; platform_system=='Windows'",
]
```

What I want to achieve is that `kaleido` will be installed in version 0.0.3 if the operating system is NOT Windows. On the other hand, if Windows is used, then I want `kaleido` to be installed in version `0.1.0post1`.

What I learned is that the first row will always be ignored, that is, if I am installing the package on a linux machine, `kaleido v0.0.3` won't be installed. On a Windows machine `kaleido v0.1.0post1` will successfully be installed.

If I switch the two code lines, the behaviour will be the opposite, i.e. `kaleido v0.0.3` will be installed on the linux machine while no `kaleido` will be installed on a Windows machine.

The actual question is, what is the correct syntax in the `pyproject.toml` to work on all operating systems?

Comment: Seems fine to me, but I have not tested.  What tool do you use to install?

Comment: I am using ``pdm``. I figured, there's an open issue on https://github.com/pdm-project/pdm/issues/46.